# Magento : Is there any way to stop to entered Dummy card details in Credit Card (saved) payment method?

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there any way to stop to entered dummy card details like 4111111111111111 in Credit Card (saved) magento?

i just want to validate card details using savecc payment method.
Any idea please share.

Comment: have you enabled 3D Secure Card Validation  in admin end?

Comment: No its magento default savecc mehtod. You can' t validate live cards